# How to set a Drawable (ripple-drawable) as background of a span?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

How can I set the background of a part of a textView to a drawable with a ripple effect?

```
spannableString.setSpan(
            BackgroundColorSpan(ANYCOLOR), startFocus, endFocus,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
```

This code can just set the background to a color, but not to a XML-File. How to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use clickable span for that:

```
fun getClickableSpan(action: (() -> Unit)): ClickableSpan {
        return object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                action()
            }

            override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds)
                ds.isUnderlineText = false
            }
        }
    }

  text_view.apply {
            val spannable = getSpannableString(
               getClickableSpan {
                   action()
                },
                fullString,
                clikcableString
            )
            movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
            text = spannable
        }
```

This code will provide you clickable part of text in TextView with ripple effect.

Comment: How does getSpannableString() look like? Does it 1) find where "clikcableString" starts and ends in "fullString" and 2) call setSpan() on "fullString" (after casting it to "Spannable")?

Comment: @solamour 
    fun getSpannableString(
        clickableSpan: ClickableSpan,
        string: String,
        spannable: String
    ): SpannableString {
        val result = SpannableString(string)
        result.setSpan(
            clickableSpan,
            string.indexOf(spannable), string.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
        )
        return result
    }

Comment: getSpannableString() will make a portion of the string clickable. But does it add the ripple effect to the clickable string, as the original poster asked?

Comment: LinkMovementMethod adds it, you can extend this class to draw your custom ripple